# jquery video hover 'oncanplay'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, html5-video

I have a site with dozens of videos, meant to play on hover. But sometimes it happens that they won't play immediately. So I'd need a loader div there. How to hide the loader when the video element is ready?

This is what I have, but it's not working (hiding the loading div)

```
    $(".wp-is-not-mobile .video-post").hover(function () {      
          $(this).children(".video-post__video").show();
          $(this).find("video").get(0).play();
        }, function () {
          $(this).find("video").get(0).pause();
      }); 

      $('.wp-is-not-mobile .video-post').find("video").on('oncanplay', function(){
          $(this).find('.video-loader').hide();
      });
```

Thank you!

Comment: `.on('canplay'` when you use .on() the event name doesn't have on in it

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
  $(this).find("video")[0].onplay = function () {

  }
```